# container failed to start

Tags: docker, containers

When I make and start a postgresql container, the command used is:

```
docker pull postgres:latest

mkdir -p /mydate/postgressql/data
```

```
docker run --name postgresql  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456 -p 5432:5432 -v /mydate/postgressql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data  -d postgres:latest --restart=always
```

But the container doesn't start,view container logs

```
docker logs postgresql
```

```
Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
2023-06-28 02:42:35.007 GMT [44] FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "restart"

PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
...
```

What should I do to start the container？

Comment: have a look at bottom of the log, you should see: `database system is ready to accept connections`. So you started it correctly

Comment: @larsks  But using the command docker ps , the container doesn't start, I don't understand where is the problem?

Comment: The logs show the message `2023-06-28 02:42:35.007 GMT [44] FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "restart"`.   The `--restart=always` is an option of the `docker run` command, but you're passing it into the container as a command by having it after the image name.  Try changing the run command to `docker run --name postgresql  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456 -p 5432:5432 -v /mydate/postgressql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data --restart=always -d postgres:latest`

Comment: @nigh_anxiety  Thank you very much for answering my question seriously, your answer is great, I have started the container

Comment: @玉树临风美少年 I wasn't sure if that was the only problem or I would have left it as an answer instead of a comment.  I will convert it to an answer now so you can mark this as Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container logs show the message:

```
2023-06-28 02:42:35.007 GMT [44] FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "restart".
```

which is our clue to the source of your problem.

The `--restart=always` segment is an option of the `docker run` command, but because it is *after* the image name in the given docker run command, it is instead being passed into the container as the command to be executed on start up in place of the default command for this image.

Here is the `docker run` command pattern, as per the [docker specifications](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/):

```
$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

To resolve this, change your run command so that the `--restart=always` option is before the `[IMAGE]` segment:

```
docker run --restart=always --name postgresql -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456 -p 5432:5432 -v /mydate/postgressql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres:latest
```

It can be anywhere after `run` and before `postgres:latest`.  I just put it at the front here so it can be seen without horizonal scrolling.